# How do I get the last file (based on date) in a directory?

Tags: server, php, ftp

I am connecting to a remote CentOS server and I need to get the date of the most recent file in a specific directory using PHP

I have the bellow command that will give me a complete list of files:

```
 ftp_rawlist($conn_id, "-ltr");
```

But i need to get only one file which is the very newest one. When I run:

```
 ls -tr | tail -1
```

in the command line in the server I get that file, but running it in my PHP script:

```
 ftp_rawlist($conn_id, "-tr | tail -1");
```

gives me nothing, an empty array!

What am I ssupposed to do?

Comment: Maybe the pipe adds an extra carriage return so you should use `tail -2`.

Comment: @LDC3, Nope, it is still returning an empty array!

Comment: Whatever made you think that [`ftp_rawlist`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php), which takes a directory path + options as the second argument, would take random shell commands? Voting to close as off-topic. Please ask programming questions on [so].

Comment: @muru ftp_rawlist will take \bin\ls arguments: `Traditional UNIX FTP servers also allow the LIST parameter to specify options for the UNIX /bin/ls program.` from http://cr.yp.to/ftp/list.html

Comment: @LDC3 so? Does that mean it will take random shell command as well?

Comment: @muru No, since it is not executing the shell; that is why he is getting an error. When I read you post, I thought you were angrily dismissing it, not that it should have been posted on another SE site since it deals with programming. Sorry.

Comment: @LDC3 that was how it was originally phrased, but I edited it in the five minute window. Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the list program does not understand `"-tr | tail -1"` as a command argument and is returning an error.

You need to use `ftp_rawlist($conn_id, "-tr");` and process the list after it returns. This [web site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) has a bunch of examples working with the results from the command.